# Re-directing the user when using an old hash route

Tags: ember.js

We are porting our old app to Ember and in the process of doing so we made a few changes to the URL structure. The main one is that we are not using hash routes anymore. In the past, our routes would look like `domain.com/#profile/some_id/` (singular, id, and with a hash) and on the new one it will be something like `domain.com/profiles/username/` (plural, username and without the hash).

We can handle the plural/singular change by creating the singular route and redirecting the user from the singular to the plural.

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend( {
  model( params ) {
    return this.get( "store" ).findRecord( "profile", params.id );
  },

  afterModel( model ) {
    this.transitionTo( "profiles", model.get( "username" ) );
  },
} );
```

Without the hash, redirecting from singular and id to plural and username works. With a hash, if I add a `/` after the hash (as in `/#/profile/id`), it also works. But with the old routes, without the extra `/` the route is not redirecting as it should.

Is there a way of telling Ember that `/#profile/` is also a hash route?